# Code should not nest more than 3 control flow statements

Tags: c#

I have to implement a bingo game and check for line, bingo or nothing for a given input where I get a 3x3 bingo card and next 15 numbers extracted.

I wrote the following function:

```
static int[,] ReadBingoCard(int rowsNumber, int columnNumber)
{
    int[,] card = new int[rowsNumber, columnNumber];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsNumber; i++)
    {
        string[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        for (int j = 0; j < columnNumber; j++)
        {
            card[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(array[j]);
        }
    }

    return card;
}

static int[] ReadNumbersExtracted(int numbersExtracted)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[numbersExtracted];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersExtracted; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    return numbers;
}

static bool CheckForBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
{
    int numMatchesFound = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
            {
                if (bingoCard[row, col] == numbers[numIndex])
                {
                    numMatchesFound++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return numMatchesFound == bingoCard.Length;
}
```

```
static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            int colMatchesInRow = 0;

            for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                for(int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
                {
                    if (bingoCard[row, col] != numbers[numIndex])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    colMatchesInRow++;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Due to some limitations of sonar analyzer I get the error:

> S134 (Error) : Refactor this code to not nest more than 3 control flow statements for CheckForBingo function.

Is there a way to split this function to get rid of this error?

Comment: Are your other functions relevant to your question?

Comment: No, just for info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use for-each to iterate through your 2d array:

```
static bool CheckForBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
{
    int numMatchesFound = 0;
    foreach (var number in bingoCard)
    {
        for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
        {
            if (number  == numbers[numIndex])
            {
                numMatchesFound++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return numMatchesFound == bingoCard.Length;
}
```

EDIT:
This is a refactored CheckForLine using a helper method to search for a values in an array

```
    static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
           int colMatchesInRow = 0;         

           for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
           {
              if (IsNumberContainedInArray(bingoCard[row, col],numbers))
              {
                  colMatchesInRow++;
                  break;
              }
           }
        }
    }
}

static bool IsNumberContainedInArray(int numberToCheck, int[] numbers)
{
    for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
    {
        if (numberToCheck == numbers[numIndex])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can`t use Linq.

Comment: @BogdanDragoş I've amended my answer

Comment: Can this strategy be applied to the CheckForLine function that i just added, as well?

Comment: Unfortunately not but you can refactor your inner for loop to be in a separate method and call that? That should keep Sonar happy. This method can also be called from within CheckForBingo

Comment: Shoul it be write as a static void function?

Comment: I imagine you can have a static function where you pass in the number you’re searching for from the 2d array and the numbers array and have your existing for loop to search and return true/false if the number is in the array

Comment: I have trouble in implementing it. Could you give an example?

Comment: I can but I’d like to know why you can’t use linq? It would make your code so much simpler